# How to justify LabelField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have long text content and I want to display it on screen with [justify alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justification_%28typesetting%29) using `LabelField` or something else. Currently, I can do right/left/center align but can't *justify* align.

Are there any custom controls that help me do this?

Comment: Note that I posted a better version of my answer's code on my blog, linked to at the bottom of my answer, after you accepted my answer.  It handles issues not asked about here, but is more verbose, so I'm leaving the answer here alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a prototype, so there may be some things it doesn't handle.  But, it should be a start, that you can use to do what you want.   Most of the important logic is in the `paint()` method.

*I'm not aware of any built-in (RIM libraries) way to do this.*

```java
public class JustifiedLabelField extends LabelField {

   /** a cache of the label's words, to avoid having to recalculate every
       time paint() is called */
   private String[] _words;
   /** the dynamic field height */
   private int _height = 0;

   public JustifiedLabelField(Object text, long style){
      super(text, style);
      setText(text);
   }

   public void setText(Object text) {
      // update the words cache when text changes
      _words = split((String)text, " ");  // NOTE: this only supports String type!
      super.setText(text);
   }

   public int getPreferredHeight() {
      // I believe overriding this method is necessary because the 
      //  justification might produce a different total number of lines, 
      //  depending on the algorithm used
      return (_height > 0) ? _height : super.getPreferredHeight();
   }

   protected void paint(Graphics g) {
      Font font = g.getFont();
      int space = font.getAdvance(' ');
      int fontHeight = font.getHeight();
      int fieldWidth = getWidth();         
      int word = 0;
      int y = 0;
      while (word < _words.length) {
         // each iteration of this loop handles one line
         int wordsInLine = 0;
         int lineWordWidths = 0;
         // first loop over all words that fit on this line, to measure
         while (word < _words.length) {
            int wordWidth = font.getAdvance(_words[word]);
            if (lineWordWidths + wordWidth <= fieldWidth) {
               lineWordWidths += (wordWidth + space);
               word++;
               wordsInLine++;
            } else {
               break;
            }
         }

         // how much total space (gap) should be placed between every two words?
         int gapSpacing = 0;
         if (word == _words.length) {
            // don't justify at all on last line
            gapSpacing = space;
         } else if (wordsInLine != 1) {
            gapSpacing = (fieldWidth - (lineWordWidths - wordsInLine * space)) / (wordsInLine - 1);
         }

         int x = 0;
         // now actually draw the words, with added spacing
         for (int j = word - wordsInLine; j < word; j++) {
            int span = g.drawText(_words[j], x, y);
            x += span + gapSpacing;            
         }

         y += fontHeight;
      }
      _height = y;
   }
}
```

The above code makes use of a `String` `split()` method.  You can find [one possible implementation here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/String-Manipulation-split-replace-replaceAll/ta-p/620038).

Then, use the class like this:

```java
   public LabelScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      String loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. Nullam enim leo, egestas id, condimentum at, laoreet mattis, massa. Sed eleifend nonummy diam. Praesent mauris ante, elementum et, bibendum at, posuere sit amet, nibh. Duis tincidunt lectus quis dui viverra vestibulum. Suspendisse vulputate aliquam dui. Nulla elementum dui ut augue. Aliquam vehicula mi at mauris. Maecenas placerat, nisl at consequat rhoncus, sem nunc gravida justo, quis eleifend arcu velit quis lacus. Morbi magna magna, tincidunt a, mattis non, imperdiet vitae, tellus. Sed odio est, auctor ac, sollicitudin in, consequat vitae, orci. Fusce id felis. Vivamus sollicitudin metus eget eros.";
      JustifiedLabelField label = new JustifiedLabelField(loremIpsum, Field.NON_FOCUSABLE);
      add(label);
   }
```

producing this:

[image]

### Limitations

- I don't do anything to account for things like padding in this field
- `LabelField` allows you to call `setText()` or the constructor, with other types, not just `String`.  My class only supports `String`, but you could easily expand that.
- My class splits the string on spaces (`' '`) only.  You may want to support splitting on other characters, or even inserting dashes to break really long words.  I'll leave that to you.
- I didn't test any *edge cases*, like words that were longer than could fit in the field width.  I only tested this with a full screen width field, with small to medium-sized words.
- see Eugen's comments on [the page I link to](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/String-Manipulation-split-replace-replaceAll/ta-p/620038) for the `split()` method used

### Follow-Up

I refined the code posted above a bit, and posted it [online here](http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/can_this_really_be_this).  The newer version should handle padding, which this version does not.  It should also handle vertical size issues if you pick a string splitting algorithm that changes how many lines the `LabelField` superclass thinks the field should have.  More comments, too.